# C Struct trouble

Tags: c, struct

Below is some code I created to try to get a better understanding of how C uses structs.

As you might guess, I am not getting my desired results.

What I don't understand is how to access a struct within a struct AND I don't know what this code is actually doing.

#### EDIT

To be clearer, this code is not functioning. It is not printing the desired values. It is not printing 3 or 4 from Value or Suit.

#### Further Edit

Apparently the editor I was using was not saving the file properly. When I compiled it by hand I got the results I expected. Sorry for the confusion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct card 
{
    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int suit;
};


struct board
{
    struct card deck[52];
};


int main()
{
    struct board b;
    b.deck[0].value = 3;
    b.deck[0].suit = 4;
    
    printf("Card Value: %d Suit: %d \n", b.deck[0].value, b.deck[0].suit);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks right, and works for me. What do you see?

Comment: What is your desired result? This code has no compile-time errors at all. Your program is syntactically correct. What are you trying to do?

Comment: In this snippet it won't make any difference, but you should use `%u` to print unsigned integers, instead of `%d`.

Comment: Hello, <br/>
Can you be more specific about your problem? <br/>
The obtained results are the expected ones, what are the results you desire? <br/>
You need an explanation for this code?

Comment: Too localized?  You've got to be kidding.  I guess we're all supposed to program with NO knowledge of how memory models and hardware works?

Answer (score 2):

First determine if your struct is a true "C" struct or a "C++ struct".  While they are both similar (or identical) in typing, if you use a C++ compiler, to get a true "C struct" you need to add the following around the struct:

```
extern "C" {
  ... // true C structs go here
}
```

*Note that this is only an example of how a compiler might manage it's memory, real compilers manage their memory in manners which optimize the use of the underlying hardware.  So the actual numbers, offsets, or order of operations might be wrong for your compiler; but, the general idea will be the same.*

With C structs, the symbols (names) for the fields are translated into offsets.  So when you use a C struct, the compiler builds an offset table based on the space each field needs (or the next address after that space which aligns with the memory subsystem).  Later when you access that field, the running program adds the offset to the address of the beginning of the struct.

```
struct MyStruct {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

struct MyStruct coordinates;
coordinates.x = 3;
coordinates.y = 5;
coordinates.z = 7;

// assuming an int takes 4 bytes, and addressing is one address per byte
// the running (conceputual) code might look like

I've labeled address 0x00002300 as "coordinate"
I've labeled ".x" as "+0";
I've labeled ".y" as "+4";
I've labeled ".z" as "+8";
```

Which would have the code perform the following memory assignments

```
set 0x00002300 + 0 (which is 0x00002300) to 0x00000003
set 0x00002300 + 4 (which is 0x00002304) to 0x00000005
set 0x00002300 + 8 (which is (0x0002308) to 0x00000007
```

Note that in this theoretical example, the compiler made sure that the offsets were large enough to hold the values.  Real world compilers might use more or less than a +4 offset for an int because their ints might take up more or fewer than 4 bytes, the address may not be one address per byte, or the memory subsystem might not be able to fetch an int from certain addresses.  (Many memory subsystems must "align" data to the width of the data bus).

When you start mixing in arrays, the compiler keeps a note of the size of the whole struct, and uses that as an offset based on the array index.  So

```
struct MyStruct coordinates[10];

coordinates[3].x = 3;
coordinates[3].y = 5;
coordinates[3].z = 7;

// assuming an int takes 4 bytes, addressing is one address per byte,
// and the entire "coordinates" struct takes up 12 bytes,
// the running (conceputual) code might look like

I've labeled address 0x00002300 as "coordinate"
I've labeled ".x" as "+0";
I've labeled ".y" as "+4";
I've labeled ".z" as "+8";
I've labeled the coordinate offset to be +12 which is "C" in Hex
```

Which would have the code perform the following memory assignments

```
set 0x00002300 + (3*c = 0x24) + 0 (which is 0x00002324) to 0x00000003
set 0x00002300 + (3*c = 0x24) + 4 (which is 0x00002328) to 0x00000005
set 0x00002300 + (3*c = 0x24) + 8 (which is (0x000232c) to 0x00000007
```

As for C++ structs, they are really C++ classes with the "default" scope set to "public" so

```
struct MyStruct {
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};
```

Compiled by a C++ compiler without the surrounding "extern "C" {" directive, will be treated exactly like

```
class MyStruct {
  public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

And will rely heavily on the default implementations for the Constructor, copy-Constructor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No problem found in your program..  what is your desired output?

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.exe
Card Value: 3 Suit: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A member of a `struct` is accessed by subscripting: `board.deck` accesses the `deck` member of the struct instance kept by the local variable `board`. `board.deck` is an array of `card`'s, so further subscripting (via array bracket notation) is used to access an individual `card` instance. Then again, the dot notation is used to access a member of this very first `card` structure in `board`.

Comment: Apparently, I am too new to upvote your answer but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is correct and has no errors.